# How do I simply send my rails website to my designer so he can finish the design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, methodology

Basically I need to send to my designer a non-finished rails website.

My Designer doesn't have ruby / Rails environnement installed and should be able to:

- modify the CSS
- add some html elements

I can manually check the diff after he worked.
Is there a way that I can make an easy extraction of my app or giving an access to the deployed one with capacity to re-root the css from his files?

Comment: do you use version control like git?

Comment: This is a rather weird/dubious choice, but a possibility (though it requires Visual Studio): http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Products/Ruby-In-Steel/article/ruby-in-steel-developer-overview

Comment: @normalocity, this is for Windows only. Better to use DVCS.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, your designer, in addition to the design, also writes code: he creates css files, and edit your views files. That makes him an integrator.

As such, he should learn the basics of source control management, such as [git](http://git-scm.com/), [svn](http://subversion.apache.org/) or any system you prefer (my favorite is [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com), for its simplicity).

It is a best practice that will allow you to save some time and avoid **a lot** of headaches when merging your revisions. A nice side effect: he will be able to easily roll-back to a previous working version of the code, should anything bad have happened.